# MATLAB Adding 2 horizontal arrays to a table as labels and a row, as opposed to 2 columns

Tags: matlab, matlab-table

I have 2 horizontal arrays I'm trying to add to a table

```
X = [1 2 3 4 5]
Y = [6 7 8 9 10]
```

and I'm trying to add them both to a 2x5 table such that the labels are X and Y is added as a row I.E.

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
```

No matter how I try and create the table, it ends up like

```
    Var 1            Var 2
 [1×5 double]      [1×5 double]
```

I've tried doing some research and couldn't really find anything. Is this something that is doable?

Comment: Vertical concatenate your data and use `array2table([X;Y])`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I could've sworn I'd tried that, but that allowed me to add a row to the table, but I had to change it to `array2table([Y])` then write a small loop to set X to the  `VariableNames`